# How to get Product details in magento observer (Order Save)

Tags: magento, product, observers

i am trying to get all the product in a order. i have the order details in my observer but i don't know how to get the product details from it. i have the following coding in my observer

```
public function getProducts($observer){
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $data = $order->getData();
 $dumpFile = fopen('observer_working.txt', 'w+'); // file is creating
 fwrite($dumpFile, 'Sample text');
 return $this;
}
```

As you can see i am creating a txt file when order is placed. and it is working. and i have the order details also. but i am unable get the product id from it.

i need following data from the order details

1) Order id.

2) array of product id which is available in the order. (only product id is enough)

please help me to get those data.

Comment: Which event are you using for your observer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Product IDs from an order, you have to get items first. Each order item have the Product ID among other data like Name or Sku.

```
$productIds = array();
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
   $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
}
```